# How to export postgreSQL database to excel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a rails app using postgres and hosting on heroku.

I 'm trying to find a way to make a button on the webpage, which can export the database to an excel file.

Does anyone has done that before? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

export data from pgsql to a csv

use apache poi to read from csv and create excel

visit [here](http://poi.apache.org/poi-ruby.html)  for more info on poi with ruby

Comment: Another question is how to export the database from app through a button in the webpage.

Comment: what all steps I wrote in my answer, just do them via a script and call the script upon click